# ZenDesk - How to update a field on user/organization update

Tags: zendesk

I am trying to figure out how to update a ZenDesk custom field when the user or organization has been updated.  I've read through the docs, I've tried everything I can think of...  All to no avail...  Below is the basics of what I want to do:

When any User or Organization has been updated (there has to be some function running as the record updates every time I blur() from a field) I want to check a custom checkbox that is on the same record.  Problem is, I can't find anything that triggers when the record is updated (via a ZAT app).

I tried using organization..changed:function(){}.  That worked to set the field, sort of.  I tried the following code, which checks the box then immediately unchecks the box???  Any thoughts at all on this?  Thanks!

```
events:{
  'organization.last_edited_by.changed':'markOrgSend'
},
markOrgSend:function(e){
  var organization=this.organization();
  organization.customField("update_checkbox",true);
}
```

Thanks for any insight into how to catch the update/save action for User/Organization records.

Comment: Apparently, per ZenDesk tier 3, this is a glitch in their software.  Their development team is working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
'ticket.assignee.user.id.changed': 'markOrgSend',
'ticket.organization.id.changed': 'markOrgSend'
```

Comment: Another option you have is to save the original values on `app.activated` (and using the `firstload` property), and then do something if the values are not the same upon `ticket.save`.

Comment: The ticket part works fine.  The issue is getting it to work with the user and organization records.

Comment: Oh I see, so you are running this in the Organization or User Sidebar? I think that was unclear to me.

If that is the case you could always listen to all of the relevant `.changed` events for organization ([here](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/events#organization-sidebar-events)) and update your checkbox upon them. Maybe you will have to listen to all of them.
Same for [User](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/events#user-sidebar-events).

Comment: I am using the .changed event.  It's in the code sample I included...?  The problem is that the field is immediately unchecked after the organization is updated.